# Apache Ignite and Spring Data - How to delete an entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite with Spring Data in Persistent Storage mode (ignite version 2.9.1 with spring data 2.2). Saving and reading Objects through the Spring Data Reposiory works fine. But when I try to delete an entity it get not removed from the storage altough when I try to use the `repo.deleteById()` method according to [the ignite spring data documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-data).

Any hints? Thank you

**Remark 1:** The `repo.deleteAll()` works fine.

**Remark 2:** The `DELETE FROM Item where Id = x` works fine with an SQL client.

**Remark 3:** I uploaded the example on github https://github.com/egloffmark/ignite-test/tree/master/ignite-test-map

**Remark 4:** I noticed that it seems to be related to the list which get obtained from the repo find method. It looks like that you can not iterate a second time through the same list? The following seems not to work:

```
        // query items
        log.info("first iteration, reading items...");
        Iterable<Item> items = itemRepo.findAll();
        // first iteration
        for(Item item : items) {
            log.info(item.toString());
        }
    
        // second iteration on same result object  <--- NOT WORKING !!!!
        log.info("2nd iteration,...");
        for(Item item : items) {
            log.info(item.toString());
        }
```

***Output*** (first execution)

```
Started MyIgniteMapApplication in 4.437 seconds (JVM running for 4.673)
XXXXXXXXXXX  application started... XXXXXXXXXXX
Number of Items: 0
storing items...
1st iteration, reading items...
Item(id=1, name=Advanced Xtra Item, code=AIX-1, attributes={Price=3.9, Color=red})
Item(id=2, name=Advanced Hyper Item, code=AIX-2, attributes={Price=9.9, Color=blue})
Item(id=3, name=Advanced Biggest Item, code=AIX-3, attributes={Price=8.95, Color=pink})
2nd iteration,...
deleting items...
Number of Items: 3
XXXXXXXXXXX  application finished... XXXXXXXXXXX
```

***Classes***

**Model Class**

```
@Data
public class Item {
    
    private static final AtomicLong ID_GEN = new AtomicLong();

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private Long id;
    
    @QuerySqlField
    public String name;

    @QuerySqlField
    public String code;
    
    public Item(Long id, String code, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this(ID_GEN.incrementAndGet(),code, name);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "ItemCache")
public interface ItemIgniteRepository extends IgniteRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

**SpringBoot Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.ontius.ignite.config" })
@Slf4j
public class MyIgniteApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyIgniteApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private ItemIgniteRepository itemRepo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("XXXXXXXXXXX  application started... XXXXXXXXXXX");

        long itemsCount = itemRepo.count();
        log.info("Number of Items: {}", itemsCount);
        if (itemsCount == 0) {
        
            // store some items
            Map<Long, Item> items = new TreeMap<Long,Item>();
            
            Item item = new Item("AIX-1","Advanced Xtra Item");
            items.put(item.getId(),item);
            
            item = new Item("AIX-2","Advanced Hyper Item");
            items.put(item.getId(),item);
    
            item = new Item("AIX-3","Advanced Ultra Item");
            items.put(item.getId(),item);
            log.info("storing items...");
            itemRepo.save(items);
        }
        
        // query items
        log.info("1st iteration, reading items...");
        Iterable<Item> items = itemRepo.findAll();
        // first iteration
        for(Item item : items) {
            log.info(item.toString());
        }
    
        // second iteration on same result object  <--- NOT WORKING !!!!
        log.info("2nd iteration,...");
        for(Item item : items) {
            log.info(item.toString());
        }
        
        // delete items <--- NOT WORKING !!!!
        log.info("deleting items...");
        for(Item item : items) {
            itemRepo.deleteById(item.getId());
        };
        itemsCount = itemRepo.count();
        log.info("Number of Items: {}", itemsCount);

        log.info("XXXXXXXXXXX  application finished... XXXXXXXXXXX");
        applicationContext.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete runnable reproducer to e.g. github? I have trouble making it run, Spring Boot and all.

Comment: I uploaded the example to github https://github.com/egloffmark/ignite-test/tree/master/ignite-test-map

Comment: The Ignore docs you linked to says delete is not supported? I think you need to call `deleteAll(ids_to_delete)` version.

Comment: No the method ```deleteById()``` is working. The problem was another basic one, see below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the "deletion" or "ignite" itself. Instead that a spring data `CrudRepository` is returning a `Iterable<T>` by default which according the specification can only be consumed once.

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
 ...
    /**
     * Returns all instances of the type.
     *
     * @return all entities
     */
    Iterable<T> findAll();
}
```

A common solution forthis problem is to define its own "findAll" method in your Repository interface which return a list type instead e.g.

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "ItemCache")
public interface ItemIgniteRepository extends IgniteRepository<Item, Long>, CustomItemIngniteRepository {
   ...  
    
    @Override
    public List<Item> findAll();
    
}
```

After that its work as expected. You can iterate a second time over the same result object.

***Output***

```
XXXXXXXXXXX  application started... XXXXXXXXXXX
Number of Items: 0
storing items...
1st iteration, reading items...
Item(id=1, name=Advanced Xtra Item, code=AIX-1, attributes={Price=3.9, Color=red})
Item(id=2, name=Advanced Hyper Item, code=AIX-2, attributes={Price=9.9, Color=blue})
Item(id=3, name=Advanced Biggest Item, code=AIX-3, attributes={Price=8.95, Color=pink})
2nd iteration,...
Item(id=1, name=Advanced Xtra Item, code=AIX-1, attributes={Price=3.9, Color=red})
Item(id=2, name=Advanced Hyper Item, code=AIX-2, attributes={Price=9.9, Color=blue})
Item(id=3, name=Advanced Biggest Item, code=AIX-3, attributes={Price=8.95, Color=pink})
deleting items...
item: Item(id=1, name=Advanced Xtra Item, code=AIX-1, attributes={Price=3.9, Color=red})
item: Item(id=2, name=Advanced Hyper Item, code=AIX-2, attributes={Price=9.9, Color=blue})
item: Item(id=3, name=Advanced Biggest Item, code=AIX-3, attributes={Price=8.95, Color=pink})
Number of Items: 0
XXXXXXXXXX  application finished... XXXXXXXXXXX
```